# How can export components to storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am practicing with the story-book and this is my code for that
`src/component/Table.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Table from './components/Table'

class Table extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>OPTION</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

And this is my storybook code
`src/stories/Button.story.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import { Button } from '@storybook/react/demo';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import {Table} from './components/Table';

export default {
  title: 'Button',
  component: Button,
};

export default {Table};
```

I want to export the `Table` from the `components` folder through the `storybook` but I don't know how to export it, can someone help me? Please, many thank

When I export like that it show me an error : `Only one default export allowed per module.`

Comment: try to remove" default" from one of the export

Comment: @Oyeme it still error

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue can come because you have two default exports in your code.

Can you try something like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {Table} from './components/Table';

export default {
  component: Table,
  title: 'Table',
};

export const sample = () => <Table />;
```

Comment: is the path to your Table component right?

maybe its placed near it like  this `import {Table} from './Table';` ?

Comment: It's show me like this: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Can you please check the export of your Table component

If it defaults exported you need to import it like this `import Table from './components/Table';`